# Conduct multiple exploratory tests on each column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a cleaner way of doing these kind of tests on a table e.g. nullity, unique values, etc and put results to a new dataframe. this code worked for me but I am sure there is a better way to do it.

Input:

```
lvl1 = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B',np.nan ]
lvl2 = ['foo','foo','bar','bar','bar','foo','foo','foo','bar','bar']
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'L1' : lvl1, 'L2' : lvl2})


df.apply(lambda x: [ 100*(1-x.count()/len(x.index)),x.dtype,x.unique()],result_type='expand').T.rename(index=str, columns={0: "Nullity %", 1: "Type",2:"Unique Values"})
```

output

```
    Nullity %   Type    Unique Values
L1  10          object  [A, B, nan]
L2  0           object  [foo, bar]
```

In the future i want to expand this to include other tests on columns and wondering what is the right way to do it in pandas

UPD: Additional question: How can I add the counts of each of the unique values to this test?

Comment: Can you give an example of your input and expected output?

Comment: `df.describe()` doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: @bakka `df.describe()` doesnt give me nullity, type nor unique values

Comment: What's *wrong* with your current solution? Seems fine to me..

Comment: @jpp it's a frankenstein of different code pieces that I am still wondering how it worked. For example, how to define the column names from the beginning without having to rename afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use a dictionary to define column names and associated functions:

```
d = {'Nullity %': lambda x: 100*(1-x.count()/len(x.index)),
     'Type': lambda x: x.dtype,
     'Unique Values': lambda x: x.unique()}

res = pd.DataFrame([{name: func(df[col]) for name, func in d.items()} for col in df],
                   index=df.columns)

print(res)

    Nullity %    Type Unique Values
L1       10.0  object   [A, B, nan]
L2        0.0  object    [foo, bar]
```

For a more functional solution, you can utilize the `operator` module:

```
from operator import attrgetter, methodcaller

d = {'Nullity %': lambda x: 100*(1-x.count()/len(x.index)),
     'Type': attrgetter('dtype'),
     'Unique Values': methodcaller('unique')}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Still I would stick to my solution since its much less verbose

Comment: @hashimov, Putting everything on one line doesn't mean "less verbose" !

Comment: I mean it is easier to copy/paste it for my everyday use